# request.FILES returns InMemoryUploadedFile

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

i made an api to upload file. I have used Django and jQuery.ajax for that. I dont know how to read File
this is my views.py file which recieves request

```
def upload(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    print(request.FILES['image'].file)
    data = request.FILES['image'].file.read()
    print(type(data))
    print(data)
    # data.encode()


    return JsonResponse(data={'message': 'recieved'})
```

and this is my HTML file from where i am sending file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" id="inp-fld">
    <button type="submit">....</button>
</form>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');



    jQuery.noConflict();
    formdata = new FormData();
    jQuery("#inp-fld").on("change", function() {
        var file = this.files[0];
        if (formdata) {
            formdata.append("image", file);
            console.log(formdata)
            jQuery.ajax({
                beforeSend: function(xhr){
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken)
                },
                url: "/upload",
                type: "POST",
                data: formdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data)
                }
            });
        }
    });


    function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}



</script>

</html>
```

this is output of request.files

```
<MultiValueDict: {'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: WIN_20190920_22_49_37_Pro.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>
```

and this is output of (type(request.FILES.get('file').read()))

```
<class 'bytes'>
```

how can i get image that i uploaded

i currently have 0 idea and experience on image processing and bytes

i just want to convert file received to jpg/jpeg

Answer (score 0):

You can save your file as:

```
f = request.FILES['file']
with open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
```

One important thing is:

`FILES` will only contain data if the request method was `POST` and the `<form>` that posted to the request had `enctype="multipart/form-data`". Otherwise, `FILES` will be a **blank dictionary-like object.**

```
<form id="form", enctype="multipart/form-data>
.....
</form>
```

The following link can be followed for more details.

[File upload](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/)

[Example](https://learnbatta.com/blog/django-image-and-file-upload-using-ajax-21/)

Comment: how can i define `enctype="multipart/form-data` in ajax

Comment: `<form>` should have `enctype="multipart/form-data` attribute, you can mention this to your `form` tag.

Comment: this is output of request.FILES `<MultiValueDict: {'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: WIN_20190920_22_49_37_Pro.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>` and this is output of form.errors`<ul class="errorlist"><li>file<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>` and this is my forms.py `class FileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= temp
        fields = '__all__'`

Comment: The above is solution for how you upload and save the files as you mention convert to file jpeg/jpg, I didn't get what you want to implement exactly, anyway request.FILES print is correct. FYI If we `print(obj)` any object that doesn't mean it print the actual value/properties of its, try to search working `__str__` and `__repr__`. Anyway if you struggling with any error further, just edit your question and include your all related code with full error traceback.

Comment: i know about `__str__` and other methods i want to just see the image that i uploaded what  view function should i write